# Grouping by in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like I am missing something really simple here, can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

I am trying to group by Sex where the Age > 30 and the Survived value = 1.

'Sex' is a boolean value (1 or 0), if that makes a difference

```
data_r.groupby('Sex')([data_r.Age >30],[data_r.Survived == 1]).count()
```

This is throwing:
    "'DataFrameGroupBy' object is not callable"

any ideas?  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need filter first and then groupby.

```
data_r[(data_r.Age>30) & (data_r.Survived==1)].groupby('Sex').count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do you filtering before grouping.

```
data_r.query('Age > 30 and Survived == 1').groupby('Sex').count()
```

Output:

```
        PassengerId  Survived  Pclass  Name  Age  SibSp  Parch  Ticket  Fare  \
Sex                                                                            
female           83        83      83    83   83     83     83      83    83   
male             41        41      41    41   41     41     41      41    41   

        Cabin  Embarked  
Sex                      
female     47        81  
male       25        41
```

IMHO... I'd use size it is safer, count does not include null values(NaN values).  Notice those different values in the columns this is due to NaN values.

```
data_r.query('Age > 30 and Survived == 1').groupby('Sex').size()
```

Output:

```
Sex
female    83
male      41
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ah. thank you Scott!  That size() does help with the output.  I was getting that grid with redundant numbers as you are showing above it, before i added that.  perfect